# dat.GUI and Complex Variables

Tags: javascript, dat.gui

I'm fairly new to dat.GUI and I'm having problems getting it to work with a more complex variable.

I have the following:

```
let complexVariable= {
    topLayer:
        {
            deeperLayer:
                {
                    deepestLayer: 20,
                    //Other stuff                    
                }
        }
}

let gui = new dat.GUI();
gui.add(complexVariable, "topLayer.deeperLayer.deepestLayer", 10, 40);
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Object "[object Object]" has no property "topLayer.deeperLayer.deepestLayer"
```

Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: I know I'm late, but doesn't `gui.add(complexVariable.topLayer.deeperLayer, "deepestLayer", 10, 40);` work?

Comment: That does work and it's what I ended up doing for this particularly implementation, it's just not the cleanest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It currently doesn't seem possible by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui/blob/master/src/dat/gui/GUI.js#L1118). They use bracket notation with the single property you pass in on the object.

```
function add(gui, object, property, params) {
  if (object[property] === undefined) {
    throw new Error(`Object "${object}" has no property "${property}"`);
  }
...
```

So what you are telling dat.GUI to do is find a top level property "topLayer.deeperLayer.deepestLayer" and that obviously does not exist on your object. It seems like more code would have to be written to support nested properties.

dat.gui would have to do something like `if (object[property1][property2][...] === undefined)` or in your case - `complexVariable["topLayer"]["deeperLayer"]["deepestLayer"];`

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that question is ~4 years old. But I was searching for the same and I found your question before realizing that it's possible. Below is E2E sample in Angular.

```js
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { GUI, GUIController, GUIParams } from 'dat.gui';

export type EditorMetadata = Array<IEditorFolder>;
export interface IDatState {
  state: EditorMetadata;
  instance: GUI;
  metadata: EditorMetadata;
}
export interface IEditorFolder {
  title: string;
  property?: string;
  tooltip: string;
  elements?: Array<IEditorElement>;
  folders?: Array<IEditorFolder>;
  folderRef?: GUI;
}
export interface IEditorElement {
  title: string;
  tooltip: string;
  options?: any;
  elementRef?: GUIController;
  target?: Object;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true })
  container: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor() { }
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.composeEditor(this.container.element.nativeElement, options, foldersMetadata);
  }

  composeEditor(container: HTMLElement, editorOptions: GUIParams, editorMetadata: EditorMetadata): IDatState {
    const
      addFolder = (folder: IEditorFolder, parent: GUI): GUI => {
        const
          { title, tooltip } = folder,
          folderController = parent.addFolder(title);

        folderController.domElement.setAttribute('title', tooltip);
        return folderController;
      },
      addElement = (folder: GUI, element: IEditorElement, target: Object): GUIController => {
        const
          { title, options, tooltip } = element,
          elmController = folder
            .add(target, title, options)
            .name(title)
            .onChange((value) => {
              console.log(model);
            });

        elmController.domElement.setAttribute('title', tooltip);
        return elmController;
      },
      createDat = (options: GUIParams, metadata: EditorMetadata): IDatState => {
        const
          state: IDatState = {
            instance: new GUI(options),
            state: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(metadata)), // Don't touch original metadata, instead clone it.
            metadata: metadata, // Return original metadata
          };

        return state;
      },
      process = (folders: EditorMetadata, parent: GUI, model: Object): void => {
        folders.forEach(folder => {
          const target: Object = folder.property ? model[folder.property] : model; // Root level or object nested prop?
          folder.folderRef = addFolder(folder, parent);
          folder.elements && folder.elements.forEach(element => element.elementRef = addElement(folder.folderRef, element, target));
          folder.folders && process(folder.folders, folder.folderRef, target);
        });
      },
      { state, instance, metadata } = createDat(editorOptions, editorMetadata);

    process(state, instance, model);
    container.appendChild(instance.domElement);
    return { state, instance, metadata };
  }
}

const options: GUIParams = {
  hideable: false,
  autoPlace: false,
  closeOnTop: false,
  width: 250,
  name: 'DAT Sample'
};

const model = {
  rtl: true,
  renderer: 'geras',
  theme: 'dark',
  toolbox: 'foundation',
  toolboxPosition: 'left',
  debug: {
    alert: false
  }
};

const foldersMetadata: EditorMetadata = [
  {
    title: 'Options',
    tooltip: 'Options AA',
    elements: [
      {
        title: 'rtl',
        tooltip: 'RTL',
      },
      {
        title: 'renderer',
        tooltip: 'Renderer',
        options: ['geras', 'thrasos', 'zelos']
      },
      {
        title: 'theme',
        tooltip: 'Theme',
        options: ['classic', 'dark', 'deuteranopia', 'tritanopia', 'highcontrast']
      },
      {
        title: 'toolbox',
        tooltip: 'Toolbox',
        options: ['foundation', 'platform', 'invoice']
      },
      {
        title: 'toolboxPosition',
        tooltip: 'Toolbox Position',
        options: ['left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom']
      },
    ],
    folders: [
      {
        title: 'Debug',
        property: 'debug',
        tooltip: 'Debug mode',
        elements: [
          {
            title: 'alert',
            tooltip: 'Alert Tooltip',
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
];
```